# May I change the past perfect continuous to the past continuous and the past perfect to the past simple with the adverb "before"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, sentence-meaning, continuous-aspect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

There are a lot of lessons about the PPC on the Internet and in textbooks, however, I've been stymied because an American friend of mine insists I can easily get away with changing the PPC to the PC and the PP to the PS.

I'd like to know if the PPC and the PC are interchangeable in such sentences and if the PC version **is considered standard English** (Might it be an Americanism?):

Is "I *had been waiting* for three months before they sent me an answer." the same as "I *was waiting* for three months before they sent me an answer." in all contexts?

Also, can I change the PP to PS in such sentences?

Is "I *had waited* for three months before they sent me an answer." the same as "I *waited* for three months before they sent me an answer." in all contexts?

In short, may I change *the past perfect continuous* to *the past continuous* and *the past perfect* to *the past simple* with the adverb "before" without changing the meaning?

Answer (score 2):

> Is "I had been waiting for three months before they sent me an answer." the same as "I was waiting for three months before they sent me an answer" in all contexts?

It is simply not possible to consider **all** contexts.

**"I had been waiting for three months before they sent me an answer"** is chiefly found in descriptive, **written** narrative and is basically neutral.

It states a fact that will be the background/context to what follows. *What follows will be in the simple past*:

"I had been waiting for three months before they sent me an answer and *when I received it, it was filled with spelling errors*."

**"I was waiting for three months before they sent me an answer"** is not necessarily background to anything. This is chiefly used in **spoken** English as a main clause that is complete in itself (and sounds very much like a complaint.)

Comment: Another possibility is _I had been waiting for three months **when** they [finally] sent me an answer_.

Comment: So, PPC is for the background of a written narrative, whereas PC for stating something in a casual dialogue, is that it? You write that the PC there isn't not *necessarily* background, but can it be?

Comment: Would it sound jarring in this context?

"I *was waiting* for three months before they sent me an answer and when I received it, it was filled with spelling errors."

Comment: “I waited three for them to send me an answer, and when I received it, it was . . .”

Comment: @Let *You write that the PC there isn't not necessarily background, but can it be?* This sounds very much as if you are trying to force your suggestion into a position that it does not suit. The adverb phrase "*not necessarily*" means that some action is not compulsory or invariable. I re-emphasise that the first clause of Xanne's version would be far more usual in spoken English and can correctly serve as a single main clause, whereas it is unlikely that “*I had waited three for them to send me an answer*" is unlikely to be used in that way.

Comment: I meant to say “three months.”